# float: none in a media inquiry not functioning

Tags: css

I can't get the image to respond to the media inquiry.
I know that the query path works, when I use the `display: none` property the image disappears.

What I would like to do, is 'un-float' the image' at the smaller screen size, so it lays beneath the header text.

I cannot get the `float: none` property to work inside the media inquiry.

http://uploadpie.com/XRPSY

**Here is the image in the HTML**

```
<header class="headercontainer">
    <img src="img/MR.jpg" class="profile-photo">
    <p>30 years experience in Metro-Detroit law</p>
    <h1>Marcia Ross</h1>
</header>

.headercontainer .profile-photo {
    /*display: block;  Will allow us to use auto margins to center the element*/
    max-width: 150px;
    margin: 0 25% 30px -150px;
    /* Here is from above, margin auto technique to center the image   the img is actually defaulted inline display */
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: right;
}
.headercontainer .profile-photo {
    /*display: block;  Will allow us to use auto margins to center the element*/
    max-width: 150px;
    margin: 0 25% 30px -150px;
    /* Here is from above, margin auto technique to center the image   the img is actually defaulted inline display */
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 943px) {
    .bragbanner {
        display: none;
    }
    .headercontainer img {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your media query selector is being overwritten by selector above that which is

```
.headercontainer .profile-photo
```

You've to be more specific in your media query selector such as:

```
.profile-photo
```

Comment: No need to overqualify the element, just using the class will do.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `.headercontainer .profile-photo` everywhere BUT in the media query?

An element (`img` in this case) has a lower [specificity](http://specificity.keegan.st/) than a class - this is why your CSS doesn't work as expected.

Change the selector inside your media query to the same as the preceding ones, e.g.:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 943px) {
    .headercontainer .profile-photo {
        /* Rules */
    }
}
```